# Tabs like a little vibrate on hover in HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to create a menu but, when it's finished the tab looks like it shakes a little on hover, like when it's hovered, the text on the tab goes up a bit and then drops back to normal

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #dbdbea;
}

.tab {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #999999;
}

.tab ul {
    display: inline-flex;
    background: #999999;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 29px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.tab ul li {
    background: #999999;
    list-style: none;
}

.tab ul li a {
    background: #999999;
    color: #222222;
    margin: 0px 11.666px 0px 11.666px;
    padding: 0px 23.334px 0px 23.334px;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 36px;
    transition: 1s;
}

.tab ul li a:hover {
    background: #666666;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 30px 35px 30px 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried everything I could but, the results still weren't what I wanted, i was really confused about how to fix this bug

can someone tell me what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. We have removed some flex utilities and give hover effect using pseudo-element with the transition.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/p41tnefh/4/

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #dbdbea;
}

.tab ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #999;
  padding-left: 15px;
  list-style: none
}

.tab ul li {
  align-items: center;
  background: #999;
}

.tab ul li a {
  color: #222222;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 29px 25px;
  transition: 1s;
  display: block;
  background: #999;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tab ul li a::before {
  content: '';
  display: black;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  background: #666666;
  height: 50%;
  width: 80%;
  transition: 0.6s all ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s all ease-in-out;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.tab ul li a:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```